# fetching data from Sanity returns undefined (Next.js + Sanity)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, sanity

I have page where I want to add some actualities. These actualities will be first set in the Sanity and then fetched via Next.js .

My Sanity schema

```
export default{
    name:"actuality",
    title:"Aktuality",
    type:"document",
    fields:[
        {
            name:"headline",
            title:"Nadpis",
            type:"string"
        },
        {
            name:"publishedAt",
            title:"Datum zveřejnění",
            type:"datetime"
        },
        {
            name:"body",
            title:"Text",
            type:"blockContent"
        }
    ],

    preview:{
        select:{
            title:"headline",
        }
    }
}
```

Problem is in fetching the data.

If I do this it will work, but will return only first actuality in the Sanity

```
export const getServerSideProps = async (pageContext: any) => {
    const query = `*[ _type == "actuality"][0]`;

    const recipe = await client.fetch(query);

    console.log(recipe);

    if (!recipe) return { props: null, notFound: true };
    else
        return {
            props: {
                headline: recipe.headline,
                publishedAt: recipe.publishedAt,
                body: recipe.body,
            },
        };

};
```

But if I remove the [0] it will throw error: "Reason: `undefined` cannot be serialized as JSON. Please use `null` or omit this value."

What do I need to change in order to get an array of Actualities?

Comment: That's probably because what you get from the fetch is an array of actualities, not a single actuality. You'll need to change your code accordingly when returning the props.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the response in a data object to serialize and call {data} in your page props like this:

```js
export const getServerSideProps = async (pageContext: any) => {
  const query = `*[ _type == "actuality"]`;

  const recipe = await client.fetch(query);

  console.log(recipe);

  if (!recipe) return { props: null, notFound: true };
  else
    return {
      props: {
        data: {
          headline: recipe.headline,
          publishedAt: recipe.publishedAt,
          body: recipe.body,
        },
      },
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Few things:

1. it returns an array if you remove `[0]`, you can do return just the data, regardless an array or not.

```
props: {
  data: recipe
}
```

2. if you want to return single data with obj vallue as multiple props

```
props: {...recipe}
```